How to display hierarchy with bootstrap rows - columns
I currently have a flat list that represents multilevel hierarchical data, then convert it to hierarchy. But when trying to display it in a vertical diagram like manner I'm at total loss as the visualization of the ordering is not quite right.
Model
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class ScriptHierarchy
    {
        public int IdScript_FK { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public int BreadthDepth { get; set; }

        public List<ScriptHierarchy> Children = new List<ScriptHierarchy>();
    }
}

Controller
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<ScriptHierarchy> model = new List<ScriptHierarchy>
            {
                new ScriptHierarchy
                {
                    IdScript_FK = 1,
                    ParentId = null,
                    Id = 1,
                    Title = "Greeting",
                    Level = 1,
                    BreadthDepth = 1
                },
                new ScriptHierarchy
                {
                    IdScript_FK = 1,
                    ParentId = 1,
                    Id = 2,
                    Title = "Benefits",
                    Level = 2,
                    BreadthDepth = 2
                },
                new ScriptHierarchy
                {
                    IdScript_FK = 1,
                    ParentId = 2,
                    Id = 3,
                    Title = "Objections",
                    Level = 3,
                    BreadthDepth = 3
                },
                new ScriptHierarchy
                {
                    IdScript_FK = 1,
                    ParentId = 2,
                    Id = 4,
                    Title = "Closing - Sale",
                    Level = 3,
                    BreadthDepth = 4
                },
                new ScriptHierarchy
                {
                    IdScript_FK = 1,
                    ParentId = 3,
                    Id = 4,
                    Title = "Closing - Sale",
                    Level = 4,
                    BreadthDepth = 5
                },
                new ScriptHierarchy
                {
                    IdScript_FK = 1,
                    ParentId = 3,
                    Id = 5,
                    Title = "Closing - No Sale",
                    Level = 4,
                    BreadthDepth = 6
                }
            };
            model.ForEach(item => item.Children = model.Where(child => child.ParentId == item.Id).ToList());
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}

View
@model List<HelloWorldMvcApp.ScriptHierarchy>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@helper PopulateChild(HelloWorldMvcApp.ScriptHierarchy child)
{
    <div class="col">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">@child.Title</button>
    </div>
            if (child.Level == 2)
            {
                @Html.Raw("</div>")
            }


    foreach (var item in child.Children)
    {
        <div class="row">
                @PopulateChild(item)
        </div>

    }
}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <div class="container">

        @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.Level == 1))
        {
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">@item.Title</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            foreach (var child in item.Children)
                {
                @Html.Raw("<div class='row'>")
                    @PopulateChild(child)
                }
        }

    </div>
                }

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>

Here's a fiddle of what I'm doing
https://dotnetfiddle.net/JBLRUs
Current result

Expected Result


Ok, your second pass at it from the view (razor) side of thing looks a lot better. You have a recursive method that can go through and render a cell. The next thing would be loading your tree structure.
First, we fetch the flat structure. You can do away with depth/breadth, all we need is parent ID.
List<ScriptHierarchy> items = new List<ScriptHierarchy>
{
    new ScriptHierarchy
    {
        IdScript_FK = 1,
        ParentId = null,
        Id = 1,
        Title = "Greeting",
    },
    new ScriptHierarchy
    {
        IdScript_FK = 1,
        ParentId = 1,
        Id = 2,
        Title = "Benefits",
    },
    new ScriptHierarchy
    {
        IdScript_FK = 1,
        ParentId = 2,
        Id = 3,
        Title = "Objections",
    },
    new ScriptHierarchy
    {
        IdScript_FK = 1,
        ParentId = 2,
        Id = 4,
        Title = "Closing - Sale",
    },
    new ScriptHierarchy
    {
        IdScript_FK = 1,
        ParentId = 3,
        Id = 4,
        Title = "Closing - Sale",
    },
    new ScriptHierarchy
    {
        IdScript_FK = 1,
        ParentId = 3,
        Id = 5,
        Title = "Closing - No Sale",
    }
};

Now that is just the flat items/data rows, to structure that into the parent/chidren:
var groupedItems = items.Where(x => x.ParentId.HasValue)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ParentId);

foreach(var groupParent in groupedItems)
{
   var parent = items.First(x => x.Id == groupParent.Key);
   parent.Children.AddRange(groupParent.ToList());
}

var models = items.Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue).ToList();

models is what you pass to the view. It should be 2 items which your view inserts then recursively calls for the children of each.
We start by grouping all "child" items (items that have a parentId) by their parentId. For each of those we find the parent and add the children references to the Children collection. When we are done we return the top-level parent(s). Now "models" should ideally return the two top-level groups, Greeting with no children, and Benefits with 2 children. The grouping would put the two closing items under the closing item under benefits.
Update: When it comes to rendering hierarchies recursively I recommend using partial views.  We start by creating a razor view called _ScriptItem which what we will use to render a single ScriptHierarchy item:
@model ScripHierarchy

<div class="col">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block w-100" data-id="@Model.Id">@Model.Title</button>
    @if(Model.Children.Any())
    {
        <div class="d-flex flex-row w-100">
            @foreach(var child in Model.Children)
            {
                @await Html.PartialAsync("_ScriptItem", child);
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>

In your main page where you want to render the collection of ScriptHierarchy items (@Model = List<ScriptHierarchy>)
<div id="hierarchy" class="d-flex flex-row w-100">
    @foreach(var item in Model) // or Model.ScriptHierarchies etc.
    {
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_ScriptItem", item);
    }
</div>

When rendering a button for a script item the partial view checks to see if there are children, and if so, creates a new Sub-row within that partial view, iterating through the children to append them. Rather than messing with Bootstrap col-# we can use flex-row to arrange however many items fall under each child.

The problem isn't transforming the flat list to an hierarchy, even tho your solution is way cleanear than mine. I'm still having the same order of objects as my second iteration, the problem is ordering each level. Here's the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/cQoLRZ

Yes, the rendering will need a bit of work to also render recursively so children are nested under their parents. Razor partial views are a great tool for organizing rendering rather than trying to do it all in code. I updated the answer to show how that is done. I took the fiddle into a project to test it out.

I just tried it and it now shows just as I wanted, I never thought of the recursive partial view. You have no idea how much I just learned from all your feedback. Thanks a lot.
